# Enabling preg_replace_callback() replacement function if it's loaded from string

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I have input strings like

```
Wires: 8 Pairs: 4
```

The both numbers may be different for different strings

So, only dividing and only numbers can be different

I need to get the output result like

```
Wires: 2 Pairs: 4
```

That is the number of wires should become the result of diving the first number by the second one

Here is my working PHP code:

```
<?php
$input = 'Wires: 8 Pairs: 4';
$pattern = '(Wires:)(\s)(\d+)(\s)(Pairs:)(\s)(\d+)';

$output = preg_replace_callback('/'.$pattern.'/',
    function($m) {
        return 'Wires: '.$m[3]/$m[7].' Pairs: '.$m[7];
    },
$input);

echo $output;
```

But the point is, both patterns and replacements should be stored in and loaded from external JSON file as strings.

The patterns are working if I store them in the file, adding two escaping backslashes instead of one like `(\\s)(\\d+)`

But how to deal with the replacements?

If I try something like

```
<?php
$input = 'Wires: 8 Pairs: 4';
$pattern = '(Wires:)(\s)(\d+)(\s)(Pairs:)(\s)(\d+)';
$replacement = 'Wires: $m[3]/$m[7] Pairs: $m[3]';

$output = preg_replace_callback('/'.$pattern.'/',
    function($m) {
        global $replacement;
        return $replacement;
    },
$input);

echo $output;
```

I simply get

```
Wires: $m[3]/$m[7] Pairs: $m[3]
```

Comment: What if you go with `"Wires: {$m[3]}/{$m[7]} Pairs: {$m[3]}"`?

Comment: @Randommm the output is the same as mine

Comment: We only have one primitive example. How dynamic does this need to be? Are you ever doing more than dividing two numbers?  This design decision has a smell and may need a rethink.  Please [edit] your question to better express how the input may vary.

Comment: @mickmackusa Only dividing. And only numbers can be different

Comment: So the `Wires` and `Pairs` is consistent in the input strings?

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes. Again, only numbers are different

Comment: Other pages that recommend `eval()`: [calling php function from string (with parameters)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6237012/2943403) and [How to execute string php code to run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45281429/2943403) and [PHP parse function call with parameters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66183663/2943403) and [PHP Execute a string containing static function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31239955/2943403) and [PHP 7.2 - How to create anonymous function dynamically when having function body in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52579112/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't allow you to serialize functions, so to serialize a function, you need a library such as this one: https://github.com/opis/closure

If using a library cannot be your choice, another convenient but **VERY DANGEROUS** way is to use [`eval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

```
$repl = 'return "Wires: ".$m[3]/$m[7]." Pairs: ".$m[7];';

$output = preg_replace_callback('/'.$pattern.'/',
    function($m) use ($repl) {
        return eval($repl);
    },
$input);
```

Comment: shingo, you missed `global $repl` Without it I get _"Undefined variable $repl"_

Comment: @stckvrw I‘ve corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no reason to store any part of this task anywhere else because you state that only the numbers will change.

Use `sprintf()` to avoid quoting problems.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hbT7d))

```
$input = 'Wires: 8 Pairs: 4';
echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/Wires: (\d+) Pairs: (\d+)/',
         fn($m) => sprintf(
                 'Wires: %d Pairs: %d',
                 $m[1] / $m[2],
                 $m[2]
             ),
         $input
     );
```

---

Or, you can use `sscanf()` and `printf()`. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/oWucq)

```
sscanf($input, 'Wires: %d Pairs: %d', $wires, $pairs);
printf('Wires: %d Pairs: %d', $wires / $pairs, $pairs);
```

Comment: _both patterns and replacements should be stored in and loaded from external JSON file as strings._ So I presume you can't manually write the math on our own.

Comment: mickmackusa thanks, but I need the replacement prepared outside the preg_replace_callback(). It's not a problem for me to manually write it inside

Comment: Why do you _believe_ that you require the replacement to be declared somewhere else?  It is either a bad idea or you need to explain the reason for this complexity.

Comment: @mickmackusa There are also another patterns and replacements in JSON file for preg_replace(). But yes, you're right - I can just store there numbers for my preg_replace_callback()

Comment: I suppose you could do something like https://3v4l.org/I7iXq, but I don't see the benefit.